# osCommerce - adding tools for admin

Tags: add-in, oscommerce

Is there a way to add a tool to osCommerce without having to edit any file? Just simply place files in some dir maybe?

I need to write addon for administrator of osC that lets them print something for every order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't.

If you want to extend the admin of osCommerce, you'll have to get dirty and edit some lines of code for the existing files.

This is separate to things like the payment and shipping modules where you can just drop in some files and have it available for install.